# pod has unbound immediate persistentvolumeclaims after deleting namespace

Tags: kubernetes, postgresql-9.3, persistent-storage

I have configured the Postgres pod with static provisioning of persistence volume in my local environment . It works fine at the first time but when i delete the namespace and 
rerun the pod then its status is pending and give me error
pod has unbound immediate persistentvolumeclaims

I tried to remove the storageClassName from Persistance Volume claim but not works
I also tried to change the storeageclass from manual to  block storage but same problem

my yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  namespace: manhattan
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/manhattan/current/pgdata"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
  namespace: manhattan
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: manhattan
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: dbr-postgres
      image: postgres-custome
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        -  mountPath: "/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data"
           name: task-pv-storage
  nodeSelector:
     kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-master
```

I want my pod to be running even when i delete the namespace and rerun the pod.yaml file

Comment: Which [Cloud Provider](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) are you using?

Comment: i am running locally now

Comment: You want the data from pv to be removed or kept?

Comment: I wants to keep the persistence volume in the cluster. I want my newly created namespace to still point to previous persistence volume

Comment: @UDITJOSHI If you want to again bound your pv You need to add persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle because in the default on, Retain, it is not possible to have another claim,check more about Reclaiming [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming)

Answer (score 0):

Data will be kept in the kubernetes node because `hostpath` uses the node filesystem to store the data. The problem is that if you have multiple nodes, then your pod can start on any other node. To solve this, you can either specify the node where you want your pod to start or implement a `nfs` or `glusterfs` in your kubernetes nodes. This might be the cause of your problem.

There is one more thing I can think of that might be your issue. When you remove a `namespace` all the kubernetes resources inside it are removed as well. There is no easy way to recover those. This means that you have to create the `pv`, `pvc` and `pod` in the new namespace.

Comment: Are you sure when i delete the namespace i  need to recreate the pv as well

Comment: Because PV remains in my system even after deleting the namespace, so when I recreate the namespace with the same name again? Why it's not pointing to the pv and goes to pending state

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by using **persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy** to **recycle**. Now I can rebound the persistence volume even after deleting the namespace and recreating it

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: "/opt/manhattan/current/pgdata"
```

Comment: you should let the community members take credit for their answers, this looks like the same solution suggested in the comments.